# (Jelly Bean) Outputting an independent, native image to an external display

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am trying to relate the [Presentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html) class in Jelly Bean with Samsung's specific accessories.

From a programmer's perspective, are the [Smart Dock Multimedia Hub](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones-accessories/EDD-S20JWEGSTA) (EDD-S20JWEGSTA) and the [HDMI Smart Adapter](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones-accessories/EIA2UHUNBEGSTA?) (EIA2UHUNBEG) identical? In other words, if we ignore the USB ports and the charging ability of the former, can one write code just once for either accessory and an attached external monitor?

The documentation suggests that one can create a [Display](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html) object corresponding to an external display. In particular, that display would have its own Context, and, I imagine--though I don't understand the details yet--an independent frame buffer.

Please note that I am **not interested in mirroring**, but in querying an attached (HDMI) monitor for its native resolution and building an image for it.

Comment: Presumably they are the same, but unless somebody who owns both and has investigated this sees your question, it is unlikely that you will be able to get an answer here. Also note that `Presentation` is only for Android 4.2, and not all HDMI-equipped Android 4.2 devices support `Presentation` (e.g., Nexus 10 does, but Galaxy Nexus and ASUS Transformer Infinity do not).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It sounds that you are suggesting it is possible to develop/debug for an external display through the emulator. Is that the case?

Comment: "Is that the case?" -- not presently. It's definitely not supported in the x86 emulator images that I have tried, and I have to imagine that even if it works in the ARM images, it would be too slow for use.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. But then surely someone out there can comment about the accessory- and device-independence of developing for an external display. At least the folks behind the 4.2 API (if anyone lurks here) would not want developers to write device-, or, worse, accessory-specific code.

Comment: "But then surely someone out there can comment about the accessory- and device-independence of developing for an external display" -- not for those two specific accessories, unless they own and have tested them. "not want developers to write device-, or, worse, accessory-specific code" -- oh, I expect that either it works out of the box or it doesn't work. Whether either of those accessories works/doesn't work will depend on the accessory and perhaps on the device (e.g., Note II might not support `Presentation` but the S IV might).

Comment: @CommonsWare How do you know which 4.2 devices have support for Presentation? Is there official list - or any documentation on this. I am stuck with similar issue - my `DisplayManager` and `MediaRouter` both won't return presentation display so I can't realy initiate `Presentation` without display. I am using Galaxy Nexus - and also use microUSB to HDMI adapter. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699317/jellybean-external-display-not-found-with-mediarouter-or-displaymanager

Comment: @ZeC: "How do you know which 4.2 devices have support for Presentation?" -- you try it and see if it works. "Is there official list" -- unfortunately, no. "I am using Galaxy Nexus - and also use microUSB to HDMI adapter" -- that definitely does not work, as I've tried it.